# show/hide icon not fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have that problem when I resize my screen, the icon goes off my input tag, I put it in the same div but it somehow doesn't work, because that icon is included in html from javascript, is that maybe a problem?
Here's the html code:

```
<div class="skup">
      
    <input v-model="lozinka" type="password" class="form-control"  id="password"> 
      
</div>
```

Javascript link to html:

```
this.$element = element;
  this.$button = $(`<button class="btn-toggle-pass"><i class="fa ${this.options.icon}"></i></button>`);
```

Classes:

```
  .btn-toggle-pass {
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  border:none;
  }
.skup{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
}
#password {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
}
```

This is how it's supposed to look:
[image]
I could fix that with margins but that's not practical. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The way I would do it is much the same as you: make the button absolute, position it using `right/top/left/bottom/margin/padding` css props. Also are you using vue and jquery together?

Comment: Yeah I'm using them in the same file, but when I set the div it doesn't apply the properties  which I gave to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could set that using the `right` property The right CSS property participates in specifying the horizontal position of a positioned element.

Comment: I could do that, but what should I do with class of div element? because it's not responsive, it goes out of the input box when I use etc. margin-left:20%

Comment: why would you use percentage based margin?

Comment: It's almost the same if I use pixels, when I resize the screen it can't be fixed... I think I need a div class to set it responsive? Is it right?

Comment: arent your input and button elements siblings ?why do you have both their positions as absolute